# Is it go against MVC architecture if I execute page jump in view?

Tags: ios, objective-c, model-view-controller, uicollectionview

For example:

There is a tableView cell in which is a collectionView,and every cell of the collectionView is about a goods.

[image]

When I clicked one cell of the collectionView the page will jump to goods detail ViewController.

Now there are two way to achieve it.

**One way also is the normal way is use delegate to send value to controller:**

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(limitTimeSaleCell:clickedItemAtIndex:)]) {
        [self.delegate limitTimeSaleCell:self clickedItemAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
}
```

**Another way is get current viewController then jump**:

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSString *goodsID = self.model.goods[indexPath.row];
    CQGoodsAllInfoViewController *goodsDetailViewController = [[CQGoodsAllInfoViewController alloc] initWithGoodsID:goodsID];
    // get current viewController
    CWFSpecialSaleViewController *currentViewController = (CWFSpecialSaleViewController *)[self getCurrentViewController];
    // jump
    [currentViewController gotoGoodsDetailViewControllerWithGoodsID:goodsID];
}
```

The way to get current view's viewController:

```
- (UIViewController *)getCurrentViewController{
    for (UIView* next = [self superview]; next; next = next.superview)
    {
        UIResponder *nextResponder = [next nextResponder];
        if ([nextResponder isKindOfClass:[UIViewController class]])
        {
            UIViewController *vc = (UIViewController *)nextResponder;
            return vc;
        }
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Is way two reasonable?I feel it goes against the normal MVC architecture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though you can, you should not execute the page jump in the view. The view should only be responsible for displaying the UI and all the navigation tasks should be performed by the View Controller.

Of course there there isn't a hard barrier preventing you from doing that, but it isn't a common practice specially if you are not working alone on the project. If there was a bug related with the navigation, for example, the view class would be the last one I would check.

Hope this answers :)